# Continuation of well ordered sets

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

> We shall say that a well ordered set $A$ is a continuation of a well ordered
> set $B$, if, in the first place, $B$ is a subset of $A$, if, in fact, $B$ is an initial segment of $A$, and if, finally, the ordering of the elements in $B$ is the same as their ordering in $A$.

(Halmos's *Naive Set Theory*, [p.67](https://books.google.com/books?id=lgdJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA67))

I have difficulty parsing this sentence. Is he saying that $A$ is a continuation of $B$ if:

1. $B$ is a subset of $A$
2. $B$ is an initial segment of $A$ (??)
3. Given the well orderings $(A,\leq)$ and $(B,\preceq)$, $\forall x,y\in B, (x\preceq y \iff x\leq y)$?

On point 2, I only know that $s(x)=\{y\in X\vert y\prec x\}$ is the initial segment in $X$ as determined by $x\in X$, but Halmos seems to mention the initial segment OF a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(A, \leq)$ be a well-ordered set.  An initial segment of $A$ is a subset $B \subseteq A$ that is closed downward, that is, it has the property that if $x \in A$, $y \in B$, and $x \leq y$, then $x \in B$.  That is, $B$ starts from the "bottom" of $A$ and doesn't skip any elements - as you go up, once you find something not in $B$ you'll never find something higher that is in $B$.

The connection to the notion you've seen before is that, given $B$, we can define $x = \min\{a \in A : a \not\in B\}$.  As long as $B \neq A$ this $x$ exists, and saying that $B$ is an initial segment of $A$ is the same as saying $B = s(x)$.

Your point (3) is correct, it just says that the ordering used on $B$ is the one it gets by virtue of being a subset of $A$.

Comment: So any WO-set is a continuation of itself?

Comment: Assuming that Halmos hasn't somewhere said that "initial segment" really means "proper initial segment" then yes.  I don't have that book, so you'd have to check his terminology conventions to answer that question.

Comment: I just want to confirm something: $s(x)$ is $\{y\in A \vert y\prec x\}$, right? Or is it with $\preceq$?

Comment: I was using the definition you gave in the question, using $\prec$.  Different authors may have different conventions, and I don't have Halmos' book, so I can't check his.

Comment: Yes, I was using Halmos's definition for $s(x)$, just FYI.